# Libsvm python error

Tags: python, libsvm

I'm trying to figure out what is the proper format of a **python list** to be given as input to a **svm_problem** function in python. I got the following program from the web, stackoverflow.

I have the following:

```
from svm import *
x=[ [1,0,1],[-1,0,-1],[1,0,0]]
#x=[ [1,0,1],[-1,0,-1]]
prob = svm_problem( [1,-1],x  )
param = svm_parameter(kernel_type = LINEAR, C = 10)
m = svm_model(prob, param)
print m.predict([ 1,1, 1])
```

It raises an assertion error, says assert failed: `assert len(x)==len(y)`.

But if `x=[ [1,0,1],[-1,0,-1]]`, the program works perfectly. Am I not supposed to give a train-data problem of length more than 2?

Also I don't understand what in x=[[1,0,1],[-1,0,-1]] is a label and what is the data?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`svm_problem()` takes two parameters: the first parameter of a vector of labels, and the second is a matrix of features. You get this assertion error because you are only specifying 2 labels, `[1, -1]`, as the first parameter in your call to `svm_problem`.

Example:

```
y = [1,-1,1,1]
x = [[1,0,1], [-1,0,-1], [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
prob = svm_problem(y, x)
```

Comment: I just figured that out. THank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you give 3 examples, you need to give the classes for the three inputs as well, so you need to do

```
prob = svm_problem( [1,1,-1],x  )
```

or something similar.